# import check_arrays from sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I'm trying to use a svm function from the scikit learn package for python but I get the error message:

```
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_arrays
```

> ImportError: cannot import name 'check_arrays'

I'm using python 3.4. Can anyone give me an advice? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This method was removed in 0.16, replaced by a (very different) `check_array` function.
You are likely getting this error because you didn't upgrade from 0.15 to 0.16 properly. [Or because you relied on a not-really-public function in sklearn]. See http://scikit-learn.org/dev/install.html#canopy-and-anaconda-for-all-supported-platforms .
If you installed using anaconda / conda, you should use the conda mechanism to upgrade, not pip. Otherwise old .pyc files might remain in your folder.

Answer (score 8):

It seems like "check_arrays" doesn't exist (anymore).
I fixed it with:

sudo vi /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/cluster/bicluster/bicluster_metrics.py

change this:
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_arrays
to:
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_array as check_arrays

Kind of a hack, but it works for me.

Answer (score 4):

For me...

This worked:

```
from sklearn.utils import check_array
```

Also this:

```
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_array
```

I am using version 0.16.0

> >>> sklearn.__version__
>
> '0.16.0'

Do this:

```
import sklearn

print sklearn.__version__
```

Tell us the results.

Answer (score 0):

You should change check_arrays to check_array. 
Source: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4624