# Sklearn GridSearchCV, class_weight not working for unknown reason :(

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

Trying to get `class_weight` going . I know the rest of the code works, its just the `class_weight` that gives me the error:

```
    parameters_to_tune = ['min_samples_split':[2,4,6,10,15,25], 'min_samples_leaf':[1,2,4,10],'max_depth':[None,4,10,15],
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is my code

```
clf1 = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
 parameters_to_tune = ['min_samples_split':[2,4,6,10,15,25], 'min_samples_leaf':[1,2,4,10],'max_depth':[None,4,10,15],
 'splitter' : ('best','random'),'max_features':[None,2,4,6,8,10,12,14],'class_weight':{1:10}]
clf=grid_search.GridSearchCV(clf1,parameters_to_tune)
clf.fit(features,labels)
print clf.best_params_
```

Does anyone spot the mistake I am making ?

Comment: Can you give an example of what do your features and labels look like?

Comment: features is basically an array of numbers(floats), where as labels, is ( dont know if you call that also an array or simply a vector)  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0.....

Comment: `parameters_to_tune` should be a dict or list of dicts. Your initial syntax is right. You only need to change the 'class_weight' key-value pair in the dict. (Sorry I didn't see your updates just now but you'd better preserve your original post and append your updates otherwise people will not know the original question.)

Comment: And your `class_weight` should be a list of dict, you made the mistake again...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<s>I assume you want to grid search over different `class_weight` for the 'salary' class.</s>

The value of `class_weight` should be a list:

```
'class_weight':[{'salary':1}, {'salary':2}, {'salary':4}, {'salary':6}, {'salary':10}]
```

And you can simplify it with list comprehension:

```
'class_weight':[{'salary': w} for w in [1, 2, 4, 6, 10]]
```

The first problem is that the parameter values in the dict `parameters_to_tune` should be a list, while you passed a dict. It can be fixed by passing a list of dicts as the value of `class_weight` instead and each dict contains a set of `class_weight` for `DecisionTreeClassifier`.

But the more serious problem is that `class_weight` are weights associated with **classes**, but in your case, 'salary' is the name of a **feature**. You can not assign weights to features. I misunderstood your intention at first but now I am confused about what you want.

The form of `class_weight` is `{class_label: weight}`, if you really mean to set `class_weight` in your case, `class_label` should be values like 0.0, 1.0 etc., and the syntax would be like:

```
'class_weight':[{0: w} for w in [1, 2, 4, 6, 10]]
```

If the weight for a class is large, it is more likely for the classifier to predict data to be in that class. One typical case to use `class_weight` is when the data is unbalanced.

Here is an [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_separating_hyperplane_unbalanced.html), although the classifier is SVM.

#### Update:

The full `parameters_to_tune` should be like:

```
parameters_to_tune = {'min_samples_split': [2, 4, 6, 10, 15, 25],
                      'min_samples_leaf': [1, 2, 4, 10],
                      'max_depth': [None, 4, 10, 15],
                      'splitter' : ('best', 'random'),
                      'max_features':[None, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14],
                      'class_weight':[{0: w} for w in [1, 2, 4, 6, 10]]}
```

Comment: Thank you, and that looks very nice, but unfortunately when i tried both, i always the error : ValueError: Invalid parameter class_weight for estimator DecisionTreeClassifier

Comment: `DecisionTreeClassifier` does not have `class_weight` before scikit-learn 0.16. And it is likely that you didn't upgrade from 0.15 to 0.16 properly considering the new error. (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596237/import-check-arrays-from-sklearn)

Comment: Thanks alot . it has to be something like that. I used the shell now to install it with "conda install...."   Unfortunately it is getting more and more cryptic http://pastebin.com/SuQVbuBu :( wanna give up

Comment: I just did that and get the same error as previously :(

Comment: Thanks for your update, now i am thorughly confused :( I thought class_weight could give me like factors how to weigh the different features in my classifer, otherwise i dont understand the purpose of it at all :( Could you maybe try to give me an example where weight is appropiate if it is not for features ?

Comment: updated my first according to your info, syntax error ?

Answer (score 0):

Link below is about the usage of different class_weight values. Just <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd> "class_weight" to the relevant section. It's using `GridSearchCV` to find best class_weight for different optimization goals.

[Optimizing a classifier using different evaluation metrics](https://github.com/Starignus/AppliedML_Python_Coursera/blob/master/Module_3.ipynb)