# SVM import failed after installing scikit-neuralnetwork

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, svm

I just installed Python's [scikit-neuralnetwork](https://github.com/aigamedev/scikit-neuralnetwork) using the procedure mentioned, that is;

```
pip install scikit-neuralnetwork
```

Now I can not import SVM. This line;

```
from sklearn import svm
```

gives this error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .classes import SVC, NuSVC, SVR, NuSVR, OneClassSVM, LinearSVC, \
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/classes.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .base import _fit_liblinear, BaseSVC, BaseLibSVM
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ..multiclass import _ovr_decision_function
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/multiclass.py", line 44, in <module>
    from .metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from . import cluster
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/cluster/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .bicluster import consensus_score
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/cluster/bicluster/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .bicluster_metrics import consensus_score
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/cluster/bicluster/bicluster_metrics.py", line 6, in <module>
    from sklearn.utils.validation import check_arrays
ImportError: cannot import name check_arrays
```

May I know what went wrong? I'll try using different environments next time, if that helps. Is there any way to fix this?

I am using Python 2.7 and sklearn 0.17.

Comment: may i know your version? due to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596237/import-check-arrays-from-sklearn

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.11 and sklearn 0.17?

Comment: Because you used **Anaconda**, please try this `conda update scikit-learn` in your command line then see what happens

Comment: Thank you, I updated sklearn but I don't think that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open sklearn.utils.validation and delete "import check_arrays", or use other package for example anaconda3. i check now - no problems. Or install anaconda3.5 and copy check_arrays to anaconda2.7 sklearn.utils.validation.