# Sklearn Datasets

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn

I am trying the code `from sklearn.datasets import load_iris`. For this I have installed sklearn module in my python 2.7.6 but it is showing me long error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .twenty_newsgroups import fetch_20newsgroups
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\twenty_newsgroups.py", line 53, in <module>
    from ..feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import text
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ..preprocessing import normalize
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ._function_transformer import FunctionTransformer
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_function_transformer.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ..utils import check_array
ImportError: cannot import name check_array
```

I want to know if installing sklearn module is enough or am I missing something? Please Help. Also I am working on Win 8.1

Comment: Have you installed the required numpy and scipy?

Comment: yes numpy, scipy, matplotlib are installed.

Comment: If you're on Windows you could use the packages from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-learn (maybe also re-install numpy)

Comment: What version of sklearn are you using? Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596237/import-check-arrays-from-sklearn

Comment: i am using sklearn 0.13.1

Comment: Open the cmd as administrator and try: pip install -U scikit-learn.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using sklearn 0.13.1 when the latest version is 0.18? You are very out of date and probably have dependency issues.

If you want an easier life then install anaconda. All the package versions work together with no need to compile anything.

Comment: +1 came for suggesting Anaconda. For windows user or actually anyone doing mostly data analyses with Python that solves a lot of potential headaches. That said for webdev it's most likely create some headaches...

Answer (score 1):

Installing sklearn is enough for reading the data.Probably the file is not retrieved by your version of sklearn.
Try to read the file from your drive

```
c:/Users/../site-packages/sklearn/datasets/data
```

directly and this can confirm the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the error

```
from ..utils import check_array
ImportError: cannot import name check_array
```

appears when there is a dependency version mismatch is there. To resolve the issue either
a) update to the latest version of sklearn via pip or easy_install . Or manually install 
b) Create a Python virtual environment and try this. It will help you to manage the version specific depend libraries.

My two cents : Go for Anaconda or Enthought Python distributions if latest version of sklearn is okay. Else better to use virtualenv package in python to isolate the environments and avoid conflicts.

Happy Hacking