# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mlxtend'

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, mlxtend

**Hello Everyone,**

I have an issue I have to immediately deal with it. I installed mlxtend and used the library for apriori(market research). In my first attempt it worked then next day I tried to update it with new data but it gives exactly this error **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mlxtend'**. And I read everywhere to find where my mistake is? Sadly, I couldn't find it. I updated my mlxtend to current version however, again I faced with the exact, same problem. When I try to install mlxtend I got this as it is expected **"Requirement already satisfied"**. I would appreciate and be glad if you have any suggestions? By the way, thanks to everyone who read this.

Comment: Are you sure you were running the same python interpreter in the same virtualenv both times?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know how I can be sure about it? I am an industrial enginner so I generally use JAVA for running optimization programs such as CPLEX ang GUROBI and python for k-means and sort of algorithms. I don't know the technical details.

Comment: how did you installed mixtend?

Comment: @FlavioMoraes executed pip install mlxtend

Comment: Ok, if it worked once I would tell you to uninstall and install again.

Comment: I uninstalled and tried again it successfully installs but again can’t find the module

Comment: which Os do you use?

Comment: @FlavioMoraes Windows

Answer (score 3):

Are you installing it in the Conda shell or somewhere else? To ensure it gets installed in the correct environment type

`%pip install mlxtend`

from within the Jupyter notebook (in a cell at the top) that you are working in and execute that cell.
If it installs successfully you can comment out that cell or remove it.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. However it didn't install. :(

Comment: I uninstalled all packages and even python and re-installed all of them. I installed properly and consider the virtualenv issue but this time it gave me this error

Comment: Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system != "AIX" and platform_python_implementation == "CPython"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system != "AIX" and platform_python_implementation != "CPython"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system == "AIX""..

Comment: This seems to be a problem related to scikit learn. See if the solutions fro this question help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596237/import-check-arrays-from-sklearn

Comment: @FlavioMoraes thank you sooo sooo much for your time and help! It works. I wish you the best. Again thank you 